# Get-AzureWebsite : Requested value 'Dynamic' was not found

Tags: powershell, azure

We have a set of custom powershell modules which use the Azure powershell cmdlets - they have been working fine for over a year. I just set up a new machine and whenever I try to run Get_AzureWebsite I receive the following error:

`PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Get-AzureWebsite 'anything'
Get-AzureWebsite : Requested value 'Dynamic' was not found.`

This may just be a machine setup but am worried that these comdlets may be being deprecated - appreciate if anyone can help or knows how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be fixed by updating the version of Azure PowerShell . More detail please refer to the [issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/issues/693) and [feedback](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/2559822/-error-requested-value-dynamic-was-not-found). Please refer to how to [install and configure Azure PowerShell](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/powershell-install-configure/). I didn't reproduce it on the Azure PowerShell v2.1.0. It works successfully.Please try to use the following code to get the current Azure PowerShell version .

```
(Get-Module -ListAvailable | Where-Object{ $_.Name -eq 'Azure' }) `
| Select Version, Name, Author, PowerShellVersion  | Format-List;
```

[image]

Comment: Hey Tom,Thanks for the response, I tried this command but just got an empty line printed...sorry if this is 101 but I'm not a total powershell noob. I can run other commands (eg New-AzureWebSite NewSite)

Answer (score 0):

Okay so this is versions of Azure and AzureRM cmdlets.
Working install is

`Install-Module -Name AzureRM -RequiredVersion 1.3.2`

Install-Module Azure -AllowClobber

Not sure about -AllowClobber but this was printed in the Azure Console....

PackageManagement\Install-Package : A command with name 'Get-AzureStorageContainerAcl' is already available on this
system. This module 'Azure' may override the existing commands. If you still want to install this module 'Azure', use
-AllowClobber parameter.
At C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\PowerShellGet\1.0.0.1\PSModule.psm1:1661 char:21

Guess there is a class in the Storage namespace or something

Answer (score 0):

I installed the latest azure powershell and then ran again the script.
It worked fine.

Just to add you need to restart your machine after installing latest powershell, else you might face error "the required module `Azure.Storage` is not loaded"