# Requested value 'Dynamic' was not found

Tags: powershell, azure

I am trying to run “New-AzureWebsiteJob” command from powershell  to install webjob  and getting “Requested value 'Dynamic' was not found.” as error.

Does anybody has any clues on this.

Answer (score 0):

Installing the latest version of Powershell through web platfrom installer worked for me.

Make sure you restart your machine after installing latest powershell else you will face error "he required module 'Azure.Storage' is not loaded"

Comment: Please don't add [the same answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41975846/4687348) to multiple questions. Answer the best one and flag the rest as duplicates. See [Is it acceptable to add a duplicate answer to several questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/104227/347985)